# TSQL when is memory allocated for variables (and table variables) in a stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, memory-management

I would like to know if it would make a difference if I declare the variable and the table variable below the if statement that could throw an error or not. So if the @key given as parameter is invalid the sp throws an error and is done without allocating memory for the variables or does it allocate the memory anyway?

```
create procedure dbo.FooSelect
    @key uniqueidentifier
as
begin
    set nocount on

    declare @count bigint

    declare @temp table (   FooID       bigint,
                            Name        nvarchar(100)
                            primary key (FooID))

    if not exists ( select 1
                    from dbo.Foo f
                    where f.Key = @key)
    begin
        ;throw 50000, 'Invalid key, permission denied!', 1
    end

    --#####################################################################
    -- declare better here (below the possible error) so in case of an error no memory is allocated?
    --#####################################################################

    select @count = count(*)
    from dbo.Foo

    if @count > 10
    begin
        insert into @temp (FooID, Name)
        select 
        from dbo.Foo f
        where f.Key = @key
              and f.FooID > 100
    end
    else
    begin
        insert into @temp (FooID, Name)
        select 
        from dbo.Foo f
        where f.Key = @key
              and f.FooID < 100
    end

    select *
    from @temp

    return 1
end
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a comment with some code.

@ThomasAdelbauer the variables in a TSQL script are "acknowledged" in parse time, not in run time like in a imperative language. Also memory allocation is by demand.

That said there's no difference to declare inside a block.
The example below works.

```
if (1=2)
begin

  declare @variable int
  print 'never printed'

end

set @variable = 3

select @variable
GO
```

Now if you try to use that variable BEFORE the `DECLARE` line you ill get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Given that a table variable is empty when it's created it's only really going to start using memory when you insert some rows into it.

Until then it's just some column definitions.

In other words the bulk of the memory usage is going to be allocated after the IF statement anyway so it's hard to envisage a scenario where it's going to make a significant difference.

Comment: thanks for the info - wasn't able to find a clear answer about that